# Next.js 13.4 - How to get Dynamic Route params within Middleware

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to get the dynamic segment value from within my middleware?

For example I have a dynamic route of `/app/[slug]` and I want to get the segment value of slug from within my `middleware.js`. I see there is `searchParams` in `NextRequest` and I would assume that should countain my slug with its value. However when I try to fetch that data, its empty.

I would like to check if slug is set so I can tell if the route is dynamic or not. That way I can also have other non-dynamic routes such as `/app/about`, `/app/faq`, and so on.

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  console.log(req.nextUrl)
}
```

Here is what nextUrl returns:

```
{
  href: 'http://localhost:3000/slugname',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  pathname: '/slugname',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {  },
  hash: ''
}
```

Comment: Middwares seems to run before slugs are processed: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matching-paths. So maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Here is the doc reference from next js. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-request-page#possible-ways-to-fix-it They actually removed 1 prop from Next request but added a way to replace deprecated api. Check it out and let me know if u can get it else i will cover it as full in answer to this question